# How to combine all external css files into a single file in drupal 8

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-8

In one of my project I am using bootstrap 3, slick, slick carousel modules. And I am implementing that project with custom theme. There is one requirement for loading all css files into a single file means combining all files including theme css, bootstrap css, contributed modules css into a one file? Kindly provide better solution for this requirement.

Comment: you can attempt to use drupal advagg and give a maximum file count of 1. have not personally tried this but the module does allow for aggregated css/js file count.

Comment: Hi PH83, after installed advagg and kept the file count 1 in configuration but no luck, its not combining css files into single file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CSS/JS aggregation at `/admin/config/development/performance` (Admin menu > Configuration > Development > Performance)
[image]

Comment: Hi Kien, Already enabled aggregate CSS, aggregate Javascript configurations in performance page. But no luck. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Suresh After you enabled aggregation, was the CSS/JS files still loaded separately? Did any error occur when you enabled it?

Comment: After enabled, still CSS/JS files loaded separately. But I didn't get errors. Thanks

Comment: @Suresh Do you have something like `$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;` on `settings.php` or `settings.local.php` files?

Comment: Hi @Kien, this setting $config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE; is not there in settings.php or settings.local.php of my project. why this setting?